# MongoDB conditional query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

We want to query a collection using two fields (ids) to find a specific conversation that has userOne and or userTwo with same id number like we want to find all the conversations that has 57e334af0e5fcc9e8e800177 id in userOne or userTwo

Mongoose Schema

```
 userOne: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'users'},
      userTwo: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'users'},
      created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
```

Query that we tried.

```
db.getCollection('conversations').find({

         $or : [{userOne: "57e334af0e5fcc9e8e800177"}],
         $or : [{userTwo: "57e334af0e5fcc9e8e800177"}]

     })
```

Sample Conversation Object

```
_id: "57eae04c4efbb25487a00293"

created_at: "2016-09-27T21:10:36.236Z"

userOne: "57e334c00e5fcc9e8e800178"

userTwo: "57e334af0e5fcc9e8e800177"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a single [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition because it takes an array which you can put both your fields into. From the example on the MongoDB documentation:

```
db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] } )
```

So all you'd need to do is:

```
db.getCollection('conversations').find({
    $or: [
        {userOne: "57e334af0e5fcc9e8e800177"},
        {userTwo: "57e334af0e5fcc9e8e800177"}
    ]
});
```

Comment: thank you its works on my development server but when I'm connecting with MongoDB atlas it's not pulling the data out thank you for your help i will find the error